# Ubuntu Setting Environment Variables for Django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, environment-variables

I have a Django project running on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx and Gunicorn. 
I am trying to set an environment variable in order to load a different settings file for production.  I have tried the following to no prevail.

In etc/environment I added my variable.  The file looks like this,

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

PRODUCTION="Production_Variable"
```

The value of the variable is irrelevant.

When I run printenv I can see that this variable is actually present! 
However my django project still does not "see" it.

```
try:  
    if 'PRODUCTION' in os.environ:

        from .prod import *

except:
    pass
```

I am a bit confused that printenv shows that the environment variable is present, yet Django cannot see it.   Does anything look blatantly wrong with what I am attempting?

Comment: Did you launch Django before setting the environment? Settings are only evaluated during startup.

Comment: I made sure it was getting restarted after the variable was set.

Comment: And you are validating that your import statement is run, and no exceptions are thrown?

Comment: Yes, I was worried about the same thing and did confirm there are no exceptions.

Comment: Ok, and this is your entire settings file? What is your project layout?

Comment: I finally got it working. I will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I hope this helps someone in the future who is running into the same problem.  I ended up editing my gunicorn.service file and adding the following line..

```
Environment="Production=production"
```

So my file looks like this

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After= network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
Environment="Production=production"
WorkingDirectory= # stuff

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at django own settings file.

[Django Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/)

This part might be helpful

add the custom env variable in settings file:

```
MY_CUSTOM_SETTINGS = 'hello'
```

then you can access it using:

```
from django.conf import settings
In [5]: print(settings.MY_CUSTOM_SETTINGS)
hello
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I did previously look into that, however, it is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Link-only answers are bad. At least copy in the section you think is related to the problem at hand.

Comment: my bad, added the relevant part from the link. Thanks for suggestion.